# Spring 3 scheduling with annotations - Having a look at the queue?

Tags: java, spring, annotations, quartz-scheduler, spring-3

Hello fellow Java fanatics,

We've recently changed from xdoclet generated XML files (quartz) to annotation driven scheduling in spring 3.

Now i'd like to have a look at all the queued tasks and running tasks. But i can not find a way of doing this.
I presume that i would need to get hold of the executor?

I hope this isn't too much of dumb question.

Thanks in advance!

Greetings,
David

Comment: related: http://techblog.bozho.net/?p=452

Comment: Are you looking for a GUI?  Or a DIY solution for your annotated tasks?

Comment: I'm looking for a DIY solution. It's running on a web application where we dont have any proper access to run custom tools.

Answer (score 0):

When using spring's quarts support, you have a bean of type `SchedulerFactoryBean`, which instantiates a `Scheduller`. So you can simply use `@Inject Scheduller scheduller`

Comment: Eventually ended up reverting the changes. Time is money and it took too much time :p